# Dual screen option is not showing in Settings → Devices → Displays in Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, thinkpad, display-manager

I am using ThinkPad L490. In my **Settings → Devices → Displays**, display mode or dual screen mode option is not showing. Please refer screenshot:

[image: Display settings]

Comment: The display mode options will be available only when you connect a monitor to your system. If the monitor is not connected it won't show the options.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you are using an HDMI cable to connect with any external monitor, please check if it is working properly. Changing the cables for me worked.